# Filtering an array of objects with string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two classes, A and B, a predicate function for each of these classes (isA and isB), and an array `arr` which holds a couple of instances of these two classes. When filtering the array using the predicate function it correctly returns just the requested instances and on the type level reduces to an array of just the requested class:

```
class A { }
class B { }

const isA = (
    x: any
): x is A => {
    return x instanceof A;
};

const isB = (
    x: any
): x is B => {
    return x instanceof B;
};

const arr: Array<A | B> = [new A(), new A(), new B()]

const onlyA = arr.filter(isA) // correct type: const onlyA: A[]
const onlyB = arr.filter(isB) // correct type: const onlyB: B[]
```

My goal is to write a function `getInstance()` that takes an array with string values "a" and/or "b" and returns only the instances of this/these name(s), e.g. `getInstance(["a"])` should have the same return value as `onlyA` above, and `getInstance(["a", "b"])` should return instances of A and B and on the type level `(A | B)[]`.

I tried to create a new object `Obj` that relates the strings to the predicate functions. I make `getInstance()` generic and constrain its only argument to the keys of `Obj`. However, this implementation doesn't work on the type level.

```
const Obj = {
    a: isA,
    b: isB
}


const getInstance = <T extends keyof typeof Obj>(types: T[]) => {
    const fns = types.map(type => Obj[type])
    const set = fns.map(fn => arr.filter(() => fn))

    return set.flat(1) 
}

const retA = getInstance(["a"]) // wrong return type: (A | B)[]; should return A[]
const retAB = getInstance(["a", "b"]) // should return (A | B)[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is new feature in TS5 called [const Type Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters)

Note a few amendments:

- the generic param is now const
- I take keys as varargs, not as an array
- your filtering logic was incorrect

```ts
type TypeMap = {
  a: A
  b: B
}

const typePredicates = {
    a: isA,
    b: isB,
}

const getInstance = <const T extends keyof TypeMap>(...types: T[]): (TypeMap[T])[] => {
    const fns = types.map(type => typePredicates[type])
    const filtered = fns.flatMap(fn => arr.filter(fn))
    return filtered;  
}

const retA = getInstance("a");      // A []
console.log('RetA: ', retA);

const retAB = getInstance("a", "b") // (A | B)[]
console.log('RetAB: ', retAB);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ssl=41&ssc=31&pln=21&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oF8CwAoUkYCFEow2AHsA7CAF2gEsJ4BeaACg2jegA8AuaMUgTwwBKHhxowGAPkSt2AJwCmFAK5zSnGuQp9gC4gDM4AbgzIT6ImUri8jFunacefQehEba0W9ISy2ilTUPLR09QxxzM0JMKyowOTkeWASwfgAeeAAfL2lGAG1SBQB3OCYhABpoQpLYMsrqrzKAXWiSLWgyEH4GXgSAOn1qEAoFOSZaWCFoAHpp6BIEhWAqCn4ABwUeNutO7qS8lpj23dteuQGhkbHaHCnZ%20eJF5ehVja3YjtIunB4cA%20jXgpoAAVdYKACyYDW0EYvgcvCSsgARr9TK0PoCAAqKAAm1GAYBGMFhfgR4lg5VJKJslPQaAsR2sAHMlABJEKkXQw6BpbZUYHQBQcEakHEwADWCn4BhBYMha0kTD6ysBEB4wIO7iYoI28rywKaQgOMJ8pL50H05G5qr6AFsoUxASaXmDsQo8QSiXlAYazR9BsNRu7uZaIANwBR5UxLc74ucA1do6QhEJSQFVOoE0GcUY2GiGeaAj0WRR2ZRQkwAERgStCXOOGZzeD-RnEEAKPogYhMpgAcgASkpYDxe5Ui3X0e0i6cS2XtJyFFWa5VK0ja43mFkvEbDts2x2uz2B0OftBR9Bp3WgA)

Comment: This works nicely. Your amendments work for the context I want to use this function in. Approving this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
const ObjMap = {
    a: A,
    b: B
}

const getInstance = <T extends keyof typeof Obj>(types: T[]) => {
    const fns = types.map(type => Obj[type])
    const set = fns.map(fn => types.filter(fn))
    return set.flat(1).map(type => ObjMap[type])
}

const retA = getInstance(["a"]) // (typeof A)[]
const retAB = getInstance(["a", "b"]) // (typeof A | typeof B)[]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, and how it solves the problem

Comment: This does not work - both retA and retAB are empty arrays